# How to print other command in tailnh command

Tags: linux, unix

I have a following code:

```
    if [$Value -ge 1]
     then
        echo "Value is correct"
    fi
```

I want to print this command when I execute `tailnh` command.

Could anyone let me know how can I achieve that??

Comment: What is the "tailnh command"? And you need spaces around the `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this code to be executed every time **after** calling the `tailnh` command, just add this to your `.bashrc`

```
alias tailnh='tailnh; if [ $Value -ge 1 ]; then echo "Value is correct"; fi;'
```

**PS**: what is tailnh? Never heard about it.

Comment: This doesn't let you pass arguments to the `tailnh` command. A function would be better.